# Model Train: L298 Hbridge seems to fry PCA9685

Tags: microcontroller

[image]This is my first time here.  I will be grateful for any help!  I am building an N scale train layout, powered by an L298 Hbridge module, and controlled by an Uno.  There are 4 electrically isolated track blocks, two of which are shown on the schematic below.  The setup runs fine for hours, then out of nowhere, the PCA9685 is fried, and sometimes also the Uno.  In case you're wondering, I use a lot of reed switches to detect train location, thus the mcp23017. I don't use the Uno PWM because I don't want to fry another Uno.
I cannot reproduce the problem.  At this point, I'm ready to use relays.
Bottom line question, how do I keep from burning up another PCA9685.  Best theory so far is that the ground wire from the 9685 to the 298 needs to be the same length as the PWM wire between them.

Answer (score 1):

> I suspect you mean an off-the-shelf LM2596 power module that is in
> fact meant to be wired as shown. If that is the case let me know and I
> will update my answer.

Your failure mode sounds a lot like it could be caused by injection current. This is any current unintentionally "forced" into or pulled out of a non power-supply pin, especially and input. Having so many sources of voltage raises the risk of such an error. To prevent this you must adhere to the following design rules:

- There should only be one ground and it should be the same voltage
  everywhere.
- No pin should see a voltage lower than ground or above its relevant
  IO supply voltage.

Breaking the first rule will cause unusual and sometimes unpredictable "offsets" in voltage perceived by the chips. The second rule is to prevent any current flowing through the internal protection diodes that are present on logic input pins (injection current).

It looks like the ground is indeed common, but to be sure that your schematic reflects reality, try probing different ground pins with a voltmeter. There should be little or no voltage between any such point.

You must make sure that no pin on the MCP is driven above 5 volts; a negative voltage shouldn't be possible as you've made sure the grounds are common. However, I'm quite suspicious of the 11v going to VLS on the L298 (module? do you have one of those red squares?). That part should have a separate voltage rail for logic, usually 5v, and another for the motor outputs, which you must intend to be 11v.

Although I dont think its related to your issue, some kind of anti-kickback circuit on those two DC motors might be advisible.

Comment: Wow, fast response.  Yes you are right, they are OTC LM2596 modules, 2 wires in, 2 wires out, a little screw on top to adjust the voltage.

Comment: L298 is a module with two power terminals, 6 logic pins: (enable, in1, in2) x2.  The motor output is some part of 11V depending on the PWM input to enableA or enable B.

Comment: With regards to one and only one ground, I am scared to take a ground from the logic level device (PCA9685 module) to the power ground terminal of the L298 module, but there seems to be no other way to get it there.  As far as voltage sources, the input 19V can power the arduino (datasheet says voltage regulator can handle 20) and the L298, use the PWM to take that current down in the 298 module for the tracks, and then only need one buck to bring the volts down for the servos.

Comment: I am interested in a recommendation for an anti-kickback circuit.  I don't know how to handle that with the polarity reversing.

Comment: If I understand your schematic correctly you already have the 298 ground and PCA ground connected?

Comment: Yes, I just don’t like it. I’d rather they share ground through their power supplies.

Comment: It's often helpful to connect grounds through a 1 ohm or so resistor. There should be only a small voltage drop across it.

Comment: To be clear, the 9685 module is designed for servos, so the relevant output is a ground and a PWM signal (servo power is not used). The module inherits ground from arduino, which inherits from 2596 buck module, which goes to wall transformer. L298module gets ground from another 2596 module which connects to wall transformer. My specific question is if I need to additionally connect the ground of the servo channel on the 9685 module to the 298.